# How to derive textsize from a character's width and font

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, text-size

Say I want to draw the string "5" to the screen. I've created a `Paint` object for this with the default android font.

I know how to measure text like this: 
`mTextPaint.measureText(...params...)` to get the width of the text in float format.

But now I want to do this backwards. I have calculated the maximum width (float) that the character ('5') may use.

**How do I find the right textSize using: the *string* or character ("5"), the *`Paint` object* for drawing the text and the *maximum width* I want to allow the character to take up?**

Comment: linear scaling does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = "5";
float fitw = 100.0f;
mTextPaint.setTextSize(fitw * (mTextPaint.getTextSize() / mTextPaint.measureText(text)));
```